# Why can I not read Zapiers RSS with ASP-Classic?

Tags: asp-classic, rss, zapier

I am trying to read a zapier rss-feed with Classic ASP, and I cant get I to work. When I use the same script but with another RSS-url it works fine. Example with http://www.alle.se/category/z/feed/.

Is it the https that is giving me the problem?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.async = False
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDOM.Load("https://zapier.com/engine/rss/1177776/insta-alle/")
Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item")

For Each itemAttrib In itemList
response.Write(itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("title").text & "<br>")
response.Write(itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("link").text & "<br>")
response.Write(itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("description").text & "<br>")    
next

Set xmlDOM = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")`

That calls the most recent version of MSXML

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that made no differens.

Comment: It works for me.  Here's your script running on a website I maintain - http://www.selsdongroup.co.uk/zapier.asp . I had to add a line `Response.charset = "utf-8"` to get the Swedish characters to display correctly

Comment: Thats strange... any clue on why it is not working on my site?

Comment: It has to be something to do with the server.   If you have RDP access it might be worth opening a session and seeing if you can access the feed directly using the server's copy of IE.  Maybe your tech support might have some idea.  NB It only works for me if I add the 6.0.  I suppose as a last resort you could look at doing a client side transformation with xslt, but that doesn't always work either, particularly in Firefox

Comment: Yes, I do have RDP access. There was no problem accessing the feed thru the servers console & IE.
I am very grateful for your input, John! Thanks!